# ASP.NET Core 3.1 OpenIDConnect message.state is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

So, I'm currently trying to test the oidc implicit flow of **response_type=token** in an OIDC client application I have spun up.

I can get past the `/authorize` request to my OIDC provider. However, when the response comes back to the `signin-oidc` redirect_uri in the client I get the following error:

```
Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

This is what the request to my authorize endpoint looks like:

```
GET https://localhost:44303/oauth/oidctest/authorize?client_id=...
```

[image: OIDC Authorize]

I'm then redirected to my OIDC Provider's `/authorizelogin` endpoint to accept the application. The request looks like this:

```
POST https://localhost:44303/oauth/oidctest/authorizelogin HTTP/1.1
```

[image: authorizelogin]

That returns a 302 redirect URL that looks like this:

```
https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc#token_type=bearer&access_token=<access-token>&scope=openid%20profile%20address%20phone%20email&expires_in=120&state=CfDJ....JDER
```

As you can see, the state is there for EVERY request. So I'm not sure what's going on.

Here is what my OIDC Middleware setup looks like in my ASP.NET Core client application's `Startup.cs`:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientsecret"];      
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Token;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.Scope.Add("address");
                options.Scope.Add("phone");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"],
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
                };
            });
```

Do I need to set this state somewhere in the middleware (eventhough it looks like it sets it automatically)?

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, the state is there for EVERY request. So I'm not sure what's going on.

It's a bit more complicated: if you take a closer look, you'll see the state (and the rest of the authorization response parameters) are actually part of the URL fragment, which is never sent by browsers to the remote servers they communicate with. That's why you get an error saying the state is null: the server never received it.

In your case, the authorization server you're targeting doesn't seem to support `response_mode=form_post` and returns the authorization response in the URL fragment, which is the native response mode for the implicit flow (`response_type=token`).

It's also worth noting the OIDC client middleware will never work with `response_type=token` as there's no identity token in this flow.

Instead, consider using `response_type=code` (the authorization code flow).

Comment: Okay, that kind of makes sense. But why would they provide it as an option if it’s not compatible? How did you know that it isn’t compatible? I know the code flow is best, but I’m trying to understand all the flows, and I’d really like to test token. Is it possible to do that with any ASP.NET libraries? And so does that mean that for response_type=token or response_type=id_token token that the response_mode=fragment is required?

Comment: Just because a client - in this case the OIDC middleware - sends `response_mode=form_post` doesn't mean the server has to support it. `response_mode=form_post` support is optional and defined in https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html. Your screenshot indicates `response_mode=form_post` is sent, so if you get a fragment response, it likely means the server doesn't support it at all (otherwise, it would refuse to process the request and would tell you the client can't use this mode).

Comment: Regarding your last question: you can only return an access or identity token from the authorization endpoint with `response=form_post` or `response_mode=fragment`: `response_mode=query` is explicitly disallowed. Read https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#Security for more information. So no, you can't use `response_type=token` in a server app if the server doesn't support `response_mode=form_post`.

Comment: Thank you. But, how do I know if my response is a fragment one? I know my OIDC provider supports form_post as I am assisting with the development of it, and I was able to use it with the code response_type using this client.

Comment: If the parameters are located after # (aka the URL fragment), it’s a fragment response.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help 

Comment: Okay, one more follow up, since the fragment was returned, would that explain why I was getting the error saying message.State is null, or does it still stem from the fact that my oidc server returned a fragmented response?

Comment: Well, if the intent is to support form_post, then there’s clearly an issue with how the server prepares its authorization responses 

Comment: Hmmm okay. Thank you!